# how to add a label over an image?

Tags: iphone

the view generates an image at runtime. i didnt use the iB to create it. when i try a place a label over it ,The label contents dont show up.. here's my code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UILabel *Label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 150.0, 20.0)];

    Label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"  size:15];
    Label.text=@"sdvdssdvsdv";
    [self.view addSubview:Label];


    UIImageView *Headbar=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 80.0)];
    Headbar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.jpg"];
    Headbar.opaque=YES;
    self.header=Headbar;    
    [Headbar release];
    [self.view addSubview:header]; 

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

when i change the frame to CGRectMake(0.0, 80.0, 150.0, 20.0) it shows up.. but i need it on the image.. please help me out..

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're adding header after the label so it's covering it up. try changing the order.

move

```
[self.view addSubview:Label];
```

so it is after

```
[self.view addSubview:header];
```

Comment: i figured it out.. if i add the label as a subview to the header it works fine.. [header addSubview:Label];

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2):

Switch the order to `-addSubview:` the two UI elements. The view added the last will be shown on the top.

Or use `-insertSubview:aboveSubview:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following two functions over the self.view:

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view
```

**Edited**

It seems to me that you are trying to create a custom navigation with the image as a background and the label on top.

This is not the good way to get your thing done. I suggest you to ask a new question if this is what you want.

Comment: i'm not trying to create custom nav bar. The label and the image are meant to be a part of the content of the view. i just figured it out.
if i add this i get the desired result.. thanks for your help... 
[header addSubview:Label];